# Permission Denied issue for OpenCart after upgrading

Tags: opencart

I'm getting "Permission Denied" issue on all my admin pages. This happened after I tried to upgrade from **2.0.2.0** to **2.2.0.0**. Does anybody know how to go about fixing this? I can't do anything from the admin side, so it has to be something I can do directly on the database. I'm guessing a table structure or some data has changed after I ran the installer which I need to revert manually. I don't have any backups of the dd and my host doesn't have one either.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You can do a fresh install of opencart, copy the permissions and paste them manually in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to `user groups` where you will select the user group you belong to. From there you will see `access permission` & `modify permission`. you will have to make sure that relevant items are ticked accordingly.
After ticking the items navigate back to the page and it should be accessible. If this does not work you will have to update the table `user_group` and set the permission field to include all the permissions for `Top Administrator`